# 'Set-AdfsGlobalWebContent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to change company name using 'Set-AdfsGlobalWebContent' of  powershell 4.0 .
I am using power-shell ISE but I am not able to get this command.
I am working on windows server 2012 R2
Anybody explain me  Why that command is not showing in intelligence? is I am missing something?

after executing this command forcefully it gives "'Set-AdfsGlobalWebContent' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" error.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn479343.aspx):

To use these cmdlets you must have previously installed the AD FS server role. This can be done using the Add Roles and Features Wizard in Server Manager or optionally, you can use the `Install-WindowsFeature AD-Federation-Services` cmdlet at a Windows PowerShell prompt to add the role.